# Unable to start Drill in distributed mode

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-drill

I am trying to setup drillv1.18 running. Facing the error below.

The drill-override.conf points to the zookeeper which runs on port 12181. On starting in distributed mode, it fails with the following log output.  But the embedded mode has no issues. 
It appears like permission issue, but both zookeeper, drill, zookeeper data-dir all are running under the same user.

```
2020-05-10 16:23:01,160 [main] DEBUG o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Construction started.
2020-05-10 16:23:01,448 [main] DEBUG o.a.d.e.c.zk.ZKClusterCoordinator - Connect localhost:12181, zkRoot drill, clusterId: drillbits1
2020-05-10 16:23:01,531 [main] INFO  o.a.d.e.s.s.PersistentStoreRegistry - Using the configured PStoreProvider class: 'org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.store.provider.ZookeeperPersistentStoreProvider'.
2020-05-10 16:23:01,718 [main] DEBUG o.a.drill.exec.ssl.SSLConfigServer - Using Hadoop configuration for SSL
2020-05-10 16:23:01,718 [main] DEBUG o.a.drill.exec.ssl.SSLConfigServer - Hadoop SSL configuration file: ssl-server.xml
2020-05-10 16:23:01,731 [main] DEBUG org.apache.drill.exec.ssl.SSLConfig - Initialized SSL context.
2020-05-10 16:23:01,731 [main] INFO  o.a.drill.exec.rpc.user.UserServer - Rpc server configured to use TLS protocol 'TLSv1.2'
2020-05-10 16:23:01,738 [main] INFO  o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Construction completed (577 ms).
2020-05-10 16:23:01,738 [main] DEBUG o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Startup begun.
2020-05-10 16:23:01,738 [main] DEBUG o.a.d.e.c.zk.ZKClusterCoordinator - Starting ZKClusterCoordination.
2020-05-10 16:23:03,775 [main] ERROR o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Failure during initial startup of Drillbit.
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$UnimplementedException: KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /drill
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:106)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:1538)
    at org.apache.curator.utils.ZKPaths.mkdirs(ZKPaths.java:351)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:230)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$2.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.curator.connection.StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.callWithRetry(StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.java:67)
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:81)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:221)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:35)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.createContainers(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:265)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.EnsureContainers.internalEnsure(EnsureContainers.java:69)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.EnsureContainers.ensure(EnsureContainers.java:53)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.ensurePath(PathChildrenCache.java:596)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.rebuild(PathChildrenCache.java:327)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.start(PathChildrenCache.java:304)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.start(PathChildrenCache.java:252)
    at org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceCacheImpl.start(ServiceCacheImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.coord.zk.ZKClusterCoordinator.start(ZKClusterCoordinator.java:145)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.run(Drillbit.java:220)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:584)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:554)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.main(Drillbit.java:550)
```

Version 1.17 has no issues in starting in distributed mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with the zookeeper version. Perhaps you use 3.4.X version, but the current version of Drill requires 3.5.X. As a workaround, you may replace zookeeper jar in `jars/ext/zookeeper-3.5.7.jar` and `jars/ext/zookeeper-jute-3.5.7.jar` with the jars that corresponds to your zookeeper version.

Comment: thanks. I downloaded zookeeper 3.5.7 and used it. But How would it help if I replace the jars of 3.5 with 3.4 ? My understanding is that the jars drill is looking for is not present in 3.4 at all.

Comment: Drill uses Apache Curator to work with Zookeeper, and Curator chooses which methods to use considering the version of Zookeeper present in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to the answer of Vova Vysotskyi, you may find more information in Drill documentation about this issue:

https://drill.apache.org/docs/distributed-mode-prerequisites/

> Starting in Drill 1.18 the bundled ZooKeeper libraries are upgraded to version 3.5.7, preventing connections to older (< 3.5) ZooKeeper clusters. In order to connect to a ZooKeeper < 3.5 cluster, replace the ZooKeeper library JARs in `${DRILL_HOME}/jars/ext` with zookeeper-3.4.x.jar then restart the cluster.